# Sort on unknown object.property WPF

Tags: c#, linq, object, casting

Let's say I have these 2 classes:

```
public class Foo {
  public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
  public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
  public string SomeTextPropery { get; set; }
  public object Tag { get; set; }
}

public class SomeObject {
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Description2 { get; set; }
}
```

And in my console application I do something like this:

```
var listOfFoos = new List<Foo>( );
//listOfFoos.Add(foo1) x 10
foreach (var foo in listOfFoos)
{
  var someObject = new SomeObject( );
  foo.Tag = someObject;
}
listOfFoos.OrderBy(x => x.Tag.Description2)
```

So the last part (`OrderBy`) won't work, because we don't know of what type `Tag` is.
But in my console application (frontend) I know what I set my tag to and I should be able to use a property on the `Tag` object in `OrderBy`. Is there away I can sort on `Description2` when `Tag` is of `object` type?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. Removed it from the original.

Comment: You can cast your Tag like this: `OrderBy(x => ((SomeObject)x.Tag).Description2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to cast the `Tag` property to the appropriate type:

```
listOfFoos.OrderBy(x => ((SomeObject)x.Tag).Description2);
```

Of course this requires you to actually know what the type of the `Tag` property is at runtime.

But if you want to order by a property called `Description2`, the `Tag` property must return an object that has this property anyway.

Maybe a common base class for all involved types, where the `Description2` property is defined, is the solution to your issue? Then you can change the type of the `Tag` property from `object` to this particular type and avoid the casting.

Comment: Thank you, I always know the Type in my frontEnd. Thanks so much. The piece of codesnippet did the trick. Wasn't sure about the casting.